# Get data from observabale firestoredocument

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, real-time-data

I have declared below variable

```
userDetails$: AngularFirestoreDocument<any>;
```

and below in service constructor

```
this.userDetails$ = this.firestore.collection('users').doc('key');
```

How can I get actual data from userdetails$?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `valueChanges` and subscribe to the observable.

```
 this.userDetails$.valueChanges().subscribe(value => {
    this.item= value 
  });;
```

Comment: I tried it, its showing "Observable {_isScalar: false, source: Observable, operator: MapOperator}"

Comment: Thanks, I got it, Just a question, the way I am doing is this recommended

Comment: yeah. but if you want to show the data using ngFor might as well use the asyn pipe without subscribing to the observable. `<div *ngFor="let item of userDetails$ | async">`

Comment: `this.userDetails$ = this.firestore.collection('users').doc('key').valueChanges()`

Comment: got it.. Thanks for extra tip

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `valueChanges()` or `snapshotChanges()` on it to convert it to an `observable`. Use `snapshotChanges()` if you need access to metadata.

`this.firestore.collection('users').doc('key').valueChanges()`

or

```
this.firestore.collection('users').doc('key').snapshotChanges().pipe(
    map(a => {
        const data = a.payload.data();
        const id = a.payload.id;
        return { id, ...data };
    })
);
```

Don't forget to `subscribe` to the created observable.